# Problem with Javascript loop

Tags: javascript

The problem im having is that im using a javascript loop to go through all of the elements in a form, but when I alert the different items in the form, by type im not seeing all the elements but the images that are currently within the form. I thought that the images were outside of the form but there not. I checked it when i looked at the source code. Any help would be very much appreciated. Here is the code below:

```
for (a = 1; a < theForm.elements.length; a++) {
    alert(theForm.elements[a].type + " " + theForm.elements[a].name)
}
```

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample HTML layout of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Items with the same **name**, such as **radio buttons** are actually an array of elements, so a simple loop will skip over these items.

Comment: Yes I know that, but in my form when I loop through it, i get the checkobx, text, select-one, etc... but I dont get the image. I dont understand why